# foreach and Select-String don't work for big input

Tags: powershell, foreach, copy-item, select-string

I have below:

```
$users=get-content "1.txt"

foreach ($user in $users) {
  $source      = Select-String -Path 2.txt -Pattern "$user"
  $destination = Select-String -Path 3.txt -Pattern "$user"

  $src  = $source.Line
  $dest = $destination.Line

  Copy-Item $src $dest -Recurse -Force
}
```

`1.txt` contains few thousands lines with user login on each line, `2.txt` and `3.txt` contains few tens of thousands lines with UNC Paths with `-` and `.` included.

It is working when `2.txt` and `3.txt` are very small but once they go over few tens maybe hundred PowerShell is saying that it cannot run `Copy-Item` because it cannot use a system-object as string... the error is with `$dest`, it does not say anything about `$src`.

Can you please tell me what is wrong and how should I do it?

Comment: What should happens when multiple lines in `3.txt` match pattern?

Comment: What your error and PetSerAl are saying is that you are getting multiple matches with your larger data sets. So you data is flawed or your patterns have a margin of error. Look at the output of `$destination.line` at the point of failure and you will see multiple results.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It cannot be because I generated 3 (destination folder in an UNC path) using 1 which contains unique users. But maybe is something wrong with the strings... can one blank space create the problem?...

About multiple lines in 3 matching the pattern I did not try yet but when running on few lines a second time, it just recreated the same folder inside the destination folder which was created from the first run.

Comment: I am trying to do this with streaming... next time I will run it I will report here